# Get length of same key in array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [{code:'A', number: 1}, {code:'A', number: 2}, {code:'B', number: 3 }]
```

How can I get a number of objects that has certain key in above array?

For example, The number of `code: 'A'` objects is **2**.

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter will iterate through the array and execute your callback function.  The callback function needs to evaluate to a boolean for the value to return.

```
var arr = [{code:'A', number: 1}, {code:'A', number: 2}, {code:'B', number: 3 }]
arr.filter(function(x) { return x.code === 'A'}).length
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array and store the informations like count and corresponding numbers in an object structure.

```js
var arr = [{code:'A', number: 1}, {code:'A', number: 2}, {code:'B', number: 3 }];

var obj = {};
debugger;
for (var i =0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  ele = arr[i];
  code = ele.code
  if (!obj[code]) {
    obj[code] = {
      count: 0,
      number: []
    };
  }
  obj[code].count += 1;
  obj[code].number.push(ele.number);
}

function getCount(code) {
  return obj[code].count;
}

console.log(getCount('A')); // 2
console.log(getCount('B')); // 1
console.log(obj);
```